# Losing the default file name while saving with Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Here is a common problem I have, when saving with Microsoft Word:

I get an already existing file open it, then decide I want to store a local copy of the file. While navigating the file system from with in the save dialogue I click on another file by accident which populates the filename with that file's name.

What is the quickest way to recover the original filename at this point?

Thanks for the help, I am looking for a short cut combination of keys that will allow me to recover the original file name.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: When the save dialog opens, select the filename and copy it to clipboard, then if you accidentally click on a file name just copy it back from the clipboard. There is no undo AFAIK.

Comment: CTRL-Z is the standard keyboard command for UNDO. However, as the suggested name is only "suggested", there's a good chance that UNDO is not an option in the file-save dialog as @Zina notes.

Comment: Sounds like you are clicking too fast. A way to avoid this is to use the menu rather than double clicking. Once you click and existing file and save, you've just copied onto an existing file, which means that that file is now gone and is now your new file with whatever contents you have just created. It's not a filename you want, it's the old document I think is what you mean. A name is just a name and unimportant and can be changed any time. You would have to `recover an earlier version` of the file.

Comment: So the fastest way to recover the filename is to cancel the save dialog and open it again.

Answer (score 2):

**Tested in MS Word 2016**

CTRL-Z is the standard command for UNDO. If an application supports UNDO it will generally support CTRL-Z to trigger this command. Microsoft products support this command fully.

However, this command does not function inside the Save As dialog, probably because the document title is only suggested and was never actually entered by the user.

I can see how it would be helpful to have CTRL-Z/UNDO support in this dialog as I myself have done precisely what you describe, but that feature currently does NOT work here.

As Zine noted, copying the document title BEFORE you start navigating around the folders and files is the best/only way to be able to restore the default document title.

**IF** you have not copied the auto-created/default file name before you lost it by inadvertently clicking on another file while navigating the Browse dialog, the quickest way to "recover" that file name is to cancel the Save As, and then restart it by opening the Browser dialog.

Comment: "What is the quickest way to recover the original filename at this point?" - So your saying there really isn't a way to recover the original filename?  You should make this clear.

Comment: Fair point. I got hung up on the keyboard command.

Answer (score 0):

**File name** field in Save dialog is a standard text edit control which supports one-level Undo with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. Yet it works only for user input. If you type something into **File name** field, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will replace your input with the previous value; pressing the keys once again will revert to the text you typed.

At the same time, if you accidentally select a file in the file list, **File name** is populated in another way, *without user input*. This also clears Undo history, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does not work.

So the only way to preserve the suggested file name is to copy it to clipboard when Save dialog opens. Usually it opens with input focus in the **File name** field and the suggested file name is selected, so you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to clipboard and then navigate to the location where you'd like to save the file to.